# how can i move a container to right

Tags: flutter, dart

how can i move a container to right.
I have 3 icon and i need move last icon to right so 2 other icons was at left

I writing app for flutter
[example a post from my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nrf8.png)

```
Row(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Container(
                                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                                          child: Row(
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              Icon(Icons.insert_emoticon),
                                              Text(memes.graphql.hashtag.edgeHashtagToMedia.edges[value].node.edgeLikedBy.count.toString()),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Icon(Icons.comment),
                                        Text(memes.graphql.hashtag.edgeHashtagToMedia.edges[value].node.edgeMediaToComment.count.toString()),
                                        Container(
                                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 230),
                                          child: Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use a - `Spacer()` widget to fill up space in between.

```
Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(Icons.insert_emoticon),
                      Text('10'),
                      Text(memes.graphql.hashtag.edgeHashtagToMedia.edges[value]
                          .node.edgeLikedBy.count
                          .toString()),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Icon(Icons.comment),
                Text(memes.graphql.hashtag.edgeHashtagToMedia.edges[value].node
                    .edgeMediaToComment.count
                    .toString()),
                Spacer(),  // Add this
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 230),
                  child: Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
                )
              ],
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

you can follow the answer above or add the IconComment and it is value on the same row and set the mainaxis alignement to `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` 
try the code below

```
  Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.insert_emoticon),
                Text(memes.graphql.hashtag.edgeHashtagToMedia.edges[value]
                    .node.edgeLikedBy.count
                    .toString()),
                Icon(Icons.comment),
                Text(memes.graphql.hashtag.edgeHashtagToMedia.edges[value]
                    .node.edgeMediaToComment.count
                    .toString()),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 230),
            child: Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

you can modify that margin right to make it fit perfectly